# How to show (and edit) last Slash Command in Slack

Tags: slack, slackbot

Using a Slack [Slash Command](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/slash-commands) obviously shows the output of the command as a response. Unfortunately, the command entered isn't shown, so you need to guess (or retrieve from your own memory) what the command was - and (as far as I know) there's no way to configure a Slack app to repeat/show that last command. Many of Slack's Slash Commands are relatively simple, so they leave less to guessing, but for custom integrations or third-party provided apps, it's harder to remember the last command or command history.

Silly example:

> `/remind me to set a reminder`

shows the output of that command - a help message on the `/remind`  command - but does not show the literal command tried.

Additionally, Arrow Up in the message post area also does not navigate to the last Slash Command, but navigates to the last text message entered. So, that's also not a way to view (and possibly edit) the last Slash Command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can type `/` in the compose message panel. Slack gives you a list of slash commands available. The top one is the last command used.

[image: auto complete message shows the last command used at the top]

Once you select it (or press enter), you can edit the command if you wish.

Comment: Yes, and now I also see that the behaviour in Slack's UI has changed. The last command is now available (and also remains visible / is copied again) in the message box if the command was invalid. That wasn't the case earlier.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't seem to work anymore :(